# Easiest and fastest draw a sigmoid curve with Teechart

Tags: c++, c++builder, teechart

i'm looking for a fast way to draw a sigmoid curve in Tchart. I really have difficulties to make it work. I tried to do it with Line Series and Fast Line Series but instead of a smoothed curve i obtain a straight one and i don't see an option to smoothen the curve. Is there an option that i can use to smoothen the curve or is there another C/C++ library which allows me to create bar charts and also sigmoid curves very easily and fast?

Comment: Line Series is the correct approach. Please provide more details on what you've tried, code, etc. and what exactly doesn't work. You say "_... instead of a smoothed curve i obtain a straight one ..._" What is a "_straight curve_?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `TLineSeries` `Smoothed` property to `true`.
You can find an example in the "Features Demo", sources [here](https://github.com/Steema/TeeChart-VCL-samples/blob/master/TeeNew/Series_CustomSmoothed.pas):

[image: Smoothed property]

Comment: Thank you very much Yeray, that's what i was looking for!